# String variable and double variable of same name are different?

Tags: android

How can I make it so when I refer to the display1 variable, I refer to double, and not the string? The program still refers to display1 as a string. I want the double.

```
[code]
package rechee.cool;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    double counter1=0;
    double counter2=0;



     public EditText display;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Associate the button variable with the xml reference



        display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);}
             //

             ////
```

//////////////////////////////

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.bOne:
                    display.append("1");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bTwo:

                        display.append("2");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bThree:
                        display.append("3");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bFour:
                        display.append("4");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bFive:
                        display.append("5");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bSix:
                        display.append("6");
                        break;

                    case R.id.bSeven:
                        display.append("7");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bEight:
                        display.append("8");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bNine:
                        display.append("9");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bZero:
                        display.append("0");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bPoint:
                        display.append(".");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bClear:
                        display.setText("");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bAdd:
                        // to get string of EditText 
                        String display1= display.getText().toString();
                        Double.parseDouble(display1);
                        //to test if display1 is double
                        counter1+= display1;
[/code]
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String display1= display.getText().toString();
        try {
            double dDisplay1 = Double.parseDouble(display1);
            //to test if display1 is double
            counter1+= dDisplay1;

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            //if couldn't parse to double it will throw
            //this (NumberFormatException) exception and you can catch it
            //print something like "text is not double" or do whatever you want.
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, can you answer another question, I'd rather not make another thread. My next task is to code the equal button. I want to be able to test if the +, -, *, or / buttons were pressed, and then do something. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

Comment: case R.id.bEqual:
      if (R.id.bAdd==true){
       
      }

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of `Double.parseDouble()` to a variable, or use the result of that expression somehow, right now that method call has no effect on your code.

Change:

```
String display1= display.getText().toString();
Double.parseDouble(display1);
//to test if display1 is double
counter1+= display1;
```

To:

```
String display1= display.getText().toString();
double displayValue = Double.parseDouble(display1);
counter1+= displayValue;
```